# Display Facebook wall on external website

Tags: php, html, facebook

I would like to know if it is possible to have a user enter their facebook log in info and have a php script get their facebook wall. I was looking at the Facebook developer page and saw that it was possible using the Graph API, but what I want to know is how I can do this for differant users of my site. Basically how can I have my users grant my site authorization to grab their wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this when you register your web app at Facebook. When users grant the right permissions to your website (which you set on your app's settings page on [the developer website](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)). After they get redirected back to your website from FB you get an access_token which you append to URLs you query of the Graph API. Look at the examples provided [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), the one relevant to you being *Profile feed (Wall)*. You can code everything on your own or use [existing open source code](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/).